# jquery ajax fails to parse valid json

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

So I'm made a php script to output tweets in json and now I am trying to parse with data with javascript. I've tested the data and it's valid json. When I do the request in Example 2 it works fine. When I try to parse using example 1 it fails saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token N`.  What is my problem?

**Example 1**

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "http://website.com/twitter.php",
  type: "GET",
  data: {
    twitter: 'google'
  },
  dataType: "json"
});

request.done(function(data) {
  var resp = JSON.parse(data);

  console.log(resp);
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
});
```

**Example 2**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://website.com/twitter.php?twitter=google", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    console.log(resp);
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

**JSON Data**

```
["New Google Trends features\u2014including Trending Top Charts\u2014make it easier to explore hot topics in #GoogleSearch g.co\/jmv6","Stating now, join our Hangout w\/ President Barroso on the #SOTEU goo.gl\/FZCXaJ  #askbarroso","Explore the Galapagos Islands + see sea lions, blue-footed boobies & other animals w\/ Street View in @googlemaps g.co\/ufjq","Slow connections may keep Google Instant (results as you type) from working smoothly. Our troubleshooting tip: g.co\/bve7","From @BBCNews: search VP Ben Gomes on how search has become more intuitive & the next frontier (includes video) goo.gl\/Z0ESkJ","\"Audio Ammunition\" - an exclusive 5-part documentary about the Clash from @GooglePlay g.co\/zrxn & on youtube.com\/googleplay","justareflektor.com\u2013\u2013an interactive @ChromeExp HTML5 film with @arcadefire, featuring their new single, \u201cReflektor\u201d","#askbarroso about the State of the European Union in a live conversation Thurs, Sept 12 g.co\/n3tj","Don\u2019t get locked out: set up recovery options for your Google Account now g.co\/sm4k","It's time for more transparency: our amended petition to the the U.S. Foreign Surveillance Court g.co\/gkww"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have `json` as your data type, `data` in your done callback will already be parsed so trying to parse it again is causing the error.

```
request.done(function(data) {
  //var resp = JSON.parse(data);

  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Ah! I had no idea that was going on. I guess I should have read more about $.ajax. Thanks for clearing that up. :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.ajax` automatically parses the JSON response, so `.parse` shouldn't be called separately. Use the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://example.com/twitter.php",
  type: "GET",
  data: {
    twitter: 'google'
  },
  dataType: "JSON",
  success : function(JSON,jqXHR){
    console.log(JSON.value); /* value of value */
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText); /* all returned */
  },
  error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
  }
});
```